# Convex Function Inequality - Difference Bounded by Linear Extrapolation and Quadratic Term

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a $\alpha$ strongly convex function and $\nabla f$ be $\beta $ Lipschitz then show that : 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)), y-x \rangle \, dt \le \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \frac{\beta}{2} \| x-y \|^{2} 
$$

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I don't know yet how to prove it but I do think we don't need $\alpha$ strongly convex to show it because there is no $\alpha$ anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic result in many books or slides. And it is true that we do not need $\alpha$-strongly convex here.

First, we have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(y) - f(x) &= \int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)), y-x \rangle \, dt \\
&= \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle + \int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x))- \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle \, dt.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Then, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
|f(y) - f(x) - \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle| &= |\int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x))- \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle \, dt| \\
& \leq  \int_{0}^{1} |\langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x))- \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle| \, dt \\ 
& \leq \int_{0}^{1} \|\nabla f(x+t(y-x))- \nabla f(x)\| \cdot \|y-x\| \, dt \\
& \leq \frac{\beta}{2}{\|y-x\|}^2.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
f(y) - f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x+t(y-x)), y-x \rangle \, dt \leq  \langle \nabla f(x), y-x \rangle + \frac{\beta}{2}{\|y-x\|}^2.
\end{equation}